# How to convert Markdown formatted text to TWiki formatted text?

Tags: markdown, twiki

How to convert [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) formatted text to [TWiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TWiki) formatted text?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd use https://metacpan.org/module/Markdown::Foswiki :)